# Can I keep a succulent plant on my office desk?

Tags: succulents

Can I keep a succulent plant on my office desk where there is no direct sunlight?
If yes how often should I water it?

Comment: Yes, if you choose a variety that naturally occurs in shaded conditions and not in full sunlight. Water it when the soil gets dry. Succulents store water within the plant, so not watering it at all for several weeks is less likely to kill it than over-watering.

Comment: Direct sunlight not being available isn't an issue for many, but all need reasonable daylight - does your desk get daylight?

Comment: @Bamboo No there is no daylight at all

Comment: No daylight, no plant, basically...though certain artificial lighting makes some plants possible  https://www.todayshomeowner.com/how-to-grow-houseplants-in-artificial-light/